# Caching a String with the play Framework 2.3.5

Tags: java, caching, playframework, ehcache, playframework-2.3

My dearest community, I m new to the play Framework and wanted to simply add a String to the Cache. In the next step I want to display this String on the website.

My model class looks like this:

```
package models;

public class Input {

  public String text;

  public void setText(String text){
    this.text = text;
  }

  public String getText(){
    return text;
  }

}
```

The cache is enabled in the settings. I use the default Cache (I think it's EHCache). Thanks for all your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.5/ScalaCache

There are 2 options to use Cache in Play

1. As a simple key-value store

   ```
   val maybeUser: Option[User] = Cache.getAs[User]("item.key")
   ```
2. To cache HTTP Responses

   ```
   def userProfile = Authenticated {
        user =>
           Cached(req => "profile." + user) {
               Action {
                   Ok(views.html.profile(User.find(user)))
               }
           }
   }
   ```

So if you want to cache your model class value, and you have some key to identify this model, you can use it like this:

```
   Cache.getOrElse[Input]("item.key") {
       Input.findById(connectedUser)
   }
```

Comment: The OP is clearly using Play Java though. The principles are the same, but the syntax is different, especially for caching HTTP responses. https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.5/JavaCache